# Opening Annotated shapefiles in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I've been given a number of files including some annotated shapefiles - Basically kilometre post markers and cable identification markers, to go with a polyline shapefile.  I was hoping that we could just drag 'n' drop the files over the images and lines in QGIS map window and they would show, but we get an error message (unknown file type) or the annotations just show up as blobs.

[image: image showing annotations and route with shaded relief]

The files are .DBF files, .PRJ files, .SBN files, .SBX file with an autoCAD LT Shape source and AutoCAD LT Compiled Shape, together with an .XML file.

how can I overlay the annotations and get them to show text rather than the blob?

I can click on the properties in the layer browser, and see the text that is supposed to display, but I can't work out how to get it to show.

Comment: There is no such thing as an annotated shapefile. Shapefiles are just points, lines, or polygons with attributes. According to your image you have a point shapefile. So you want to label the points with some attribute?

Comment: We have uploaded the shapefile for our route and there is another shapefile that has text in an attribute table  - I've found out that it can be dragged into the Map View area and then right-click on the properties, go to "Label" tab and select "Label this layer with..."  In the file, there are annotations under "style" and "Text" columns, which are now displayed next to the initial points.  Thanks for your answer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Layers, Properties, "Labels" tab, "Label this layer with..." Text (from drop-down menu).  Ta Da!